# How to set link color inside GridView cell

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

ASP.net:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="carrier_id,carrier_plan_id,card_id" HeaderText="Health Plan" 
         HeaderStyle-CssClass="subNav" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="health_plan" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC"
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="somewhereA.aspx?cid={0}&cpid={1}&ccid={2}" DataTextField="health_plan_title"
         NavigateUrl="somewhereA.aspx" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="True">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoBoldBlueSmall"></HeaderStyle>
     </asp:HyperLinkField>
```

By default the link color is what is driven by the browser standard but I have a condition, if met I would like the link color to change, which is done in code-behind:

```
If IsDBNull(e.Row.DataItem("isRed")) = False Then
    If (e.Row.DataItem("isRed") = "N") Then 'AND (lnk.NavigateUrl Is Nothing) Then
        e.Row.Cells(1).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red //hyperlink (which doesn't work because it is only setting the cell color)
        e.Row.Cells(1).CssClass = "redColor" //hyperlink (which also doesn't work because it is being overridden by browser)
    End If
End If
```

CSS:

```
.redColor
{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Output in browser:

```
<td class="redColor" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><a href="somewhereA.aspx?cid=90000&amp;cpid=12&amp;ccid=56">This should be red</a></td>
```

It is setting the TD in red but not the link itself.

How can I modify my VB.net code which will set the link class to `redColor` if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweaking your CSS will fix it. Your VB code can remain the same.

```
.redColor, .redColor a
{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I was able to use JQuery to do the same thing also. Thank you. +1